# different facebook like-urls (images) counting for http and https

Tags: http, https, count, facebook-like

there is a page width a lot of images **every** image got a different like button.
After changing the site to https the like-count resets (because the like-links also changed to https).

Is there any way to combine both existing counts (https and http) after that hilarious actions i made?

Just asking... xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the http link in the og:url parameter, instead of changing it to https for SSL pages.

This is also explained in other threads:

- [Like count for almost same URL (HTTP, HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531924/like-count-for-almost-same-url-http-https)
- [Having Facebook likes accumulate over https:// and http://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543089/having-facebook-likes-accumulate-over-https-and-http)

Combining the counts is not possible, as it´s a different URL.

Comment: the existing counts. not the future counts.

Comment: well, you cannot combine them, as it´s a different url. you can only choose to use one of them for the whole website.

Comment: thanx anyway. i check your answer later if no one else knows better.